# while(true) and loop-breaking - anti-pattern?

Tags: programming-practices, language-agnostic, readability

Consider the following code:

```java
public void doSomething(int input)
{
   while(true)
   {
      TransformInSomeWay(input);

      if(ProcessingComplete(input))
         break;

      DoSomethingElseTo(input);
   }
}
```

Assume that this process involves a finite but input-dependent number of steps; the loop is designed to terminate on its own as a result of the algorithm, and is not designed to run indefinitely (until cancelled by an outside event). Because the test to see if the loop should end is in the middle of a logical set of steps, the while loop itself currently doesn't check anything meaningful; the check is instead performed at the "proper" place within the conceptual algorithm.

I was told that this is bad code, because it is more bug-prone due to the ending condition not being checked by the loop structure. It's more difficult to figure out how you'd exit the loop, and could invite bugs as the breaking condition might be bypassed or omitted accidentally given future changes.

Now, the code could be structured as follows:

```java
public void doSomething(int input)
{
   TransformInSomeWay(input);

   while(!ProcessingComplete(input))
   {
      DoSomethingElseTo(input);
      TransformInSomeWay(input);
   }
}
```

However, this duplicates a call to a method in code, violating DRY; if `TransformInSomeWay` were later replaced with some other method, both calls would have to be found and changed (and the fact that there are two may be less obvious in a more complex piece of code).

You could also write it like:

```java
public void doSomething(int input)
{
   var complete = false;
   while(!complete)
   {
      TransformInSomeWay(input);

      complete = ProcessingComplete(input);

      if(!complete) 
      {
         DoSomethingElseTo(input);          
      }
   }
}
```

... but you now have a variable whose only purpose is to shift the condition-checking to the loop structure, and also has to be checked multiple times to provide the same behavior as the original logic.

For my part, I say that given the algorithm this code implements in the real world, the original code is the most readable. If you were going through it yourself, this is the way you'd think about it, and so it would be intuitive to people familiar with the algorithm.

So, which is "better"? is it better to give the responsibility of condition checking to the while loop by structuring the logic around the loop? Or is it better to structure the logic in a "natural" way as indicated by requirements or a conceptual description of the algorithm, even though that may mean bypassing the loop's built-in capabilities?

Comment: Would this question be better on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions ?

Comment: Possibly, but despite the code samples the question being asked is IMO more conceptual, which is more in line with this area of SE. What is a pattern or anti-pattern is discussed here often, and that's the real question; is structuring a loop to run infinitely and then breaking out of it a bad thing?

Comment: Good point, I guess if you posted *actual* code then CR might be more appropriate.

Comment: The `do ... until` construct is also useful for these kinds of loops since they don't have to be "primed."

Comment: The loop-and-a-half case still lacks any really good answer.

Comment: I prefer the `while(true) { break; }` method for the reasons you mentioned. You mentioned that non trivial code might bypass the exit condition but the same would be true for calling `TransformInSomeWay(input)` inside the loop. Using an additional variable also introduces another variable to the scope which would cloud up the scope.

Comment: "However, this duplicates a call to a method in code, violating DRY" I disagree with that assertion and it seems like a misunderstanding of the principle.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: VB.NET, as well as many preceding dialects (I believe dating all the way back to Cassette Basic) included "Do ... Loop" [with neither end of the loop supply a condition], and allowed code within the loop to "If XXX Then Exit Do".  That seems a little cleaner than C and offshoots which require a dummy condition at the start or end of the loop.

Comment: @supercat It's a little cleaner but I still wouldn't call that a really good answer.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: That structure goes back a *long time* [not sure about Cassette Basic, and I don't have an original PC to test it with, but certainly to QuickBasic if not before], and QuickBasic was hardly a wonderful language.  It may not be as nice as the looping in Ada, but at least it was designed for mid-exit looping.

Comment: Apart from me preferring C-style for (;;) which _explictely_ means "I have a loop, and I don't check in the loop statement", your first approach is absolutely right. You have a loop. There's some work to do before you can decide whether to exit. Then you exit if some conditions are met. Then you do the actual work, and start all over. That's absolutely fine, easy to understand, logical, non-redundant, and easy to get right. The second variant is just awful, while the third is merely pointless; turning to awful if the rest of the loop that goes into the if is very long.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stick with your first solution.  Loops can become very involved and one or more clean breaks can be a lot easier on you, anyone else looking at your code, the optimizer, and the program's performance than elaborate if-statements and added variables.  My usual approach is to set up a loop with something like the "while (true)" and get the best coding I can.  Often I can and do  then replace the break(s) with a standard loop control; most loops are pretty simple, after all.  The ending condition *should* be checked by the loop structure for the reasons you mention, but *not* at the cost of adding whole new variables, adding if-statements, and repeating code, all of which are even *more* bug prone.

Comment: "if-statements, and repeating code, all of which are even more bug prone." -- yep when trying people I call if's "future bugs"

Answer (score 15):

It's only a meaningful problem if the loop body is non-trivial. If the body is so small, then analyzing it like this is trivial, and not a problem at all.

Answer (score 8):

I've trouble to find the other solutions better than the one with break. Well, I prefer the Ada way which allows to do

```
loop
  TransformInSomeWay(input);
exit when ProcessingComplete(input);
  DoSomethingElseTo(input);
end loop;
```

but the break solution is the cleanest rendering.

My POV is that when there is a missing control structure, the cleanest solution is to emulate it with other control structures, not using data flow. (And similarly, when I have a data flow problem to prefer pure data flow solutions to the one involving control structures *).

> It's more difficult to figure out how you'd exit the loop,

Don't be mistaken, the discussion wouldn't take place if the difficulty wasn't mostly the same: the condition is the same and present at the same place.

Which of

```java
while (true) {
   XXXX
if (YYY) break;
   ZZZZ;
}
```

and

```java
while (TTTT) {
    XXXX
    if (YYYY) {
        ZZZZ
    }
}
```

render better the intended structure? I'm voting for the first, you don't have to check that the conditions matches. (But see my indentation).

Comment: Oh, look, a language that *does* directly support mid-exit loops! :)

Comment: I like your point about emulating missing control structures with control structures.  That's probably a good answer to GOTO-related questions as well.  One should use a language's control structures whenever they fit semantic requirements, but if an algorithm requires something else one should use the control structure required by the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

while(true) and break is a common idiom. It's the canonical way to implement mid-exit loops in C-like languages. Adding a variable to store the exit condition and an if() around the second half of the loop is a reasonable alternative. Some shops may Officially Standardize on one or the other, but neither one is superior; they are equivalent.

A good programmer working in these languages should be able to know what's going on at a glance if he or she sees either one. It might make a good little interview question; hand somebody two loops, one using each idiom, and ask 'em what the difference is (proper answer: "nothing", with maybe an addition of "but I habitually use THAT one.")

Answer (score 3):

People say it is bad practice to use `while (true)`, and a lot of the time they are right. If your `while` statement contains lots of complicated code and it is unclear when you are breaking out of if, then you are left with difficult to maintain code and a simple bug could cause an infinite loop.

In your example you are correct to use `while(true)` because your code is clear and easy to understand. There is no point creating inefficient and harder to read code, simply because some people consider it always bad practice to use `while(true)`.

I was faced with a similar problem:

```php
$i = 0
$key = $str.'0';
$key1 = $str1.'0';
while (isset($array][$key] || isset($array][$key1])
{
    if (isset($array][$key]))
    {
        // Code
    }
    else
    {
        // Code
    }
    $key = $str.++$i;
    $key1 = $str1.$i;
}
```

Using `do ... while(true)` avoids `isset($array][$key]` unnecessarily being called twice, the code it shorter, cleaner, and easier to read. There is absolutely no risk of an infinite loop bug being introduced with `else break;` at the end.

```php
$i = -1;
do
{
    $key = $str.++$i;
    $key1 = $str1.$i;
    if (isset($array[$key]))
    {
        // Code
    }
    elseif (isset($array[$key1]))
    {
        // Code
    }
    else
        break;
} while (true);
```

It's good to follow *good practices* and avoid *bad practices* but there are always exceptions and it's important to keep an open mind and realise those exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Your alternatives are not as bad as you may think. Good code should:

1. Clearly indicate with good variable names / comments under what conditions the loop should be terminated. (The breaking condition should not be hidden)
2. Clearly indicate what is the order of doing operations. This is where putting the optional 3rd operation ( `DoSomethingElseTo(input)` ) inside the if is a good idea.

That said, it is easy to let perfectionist, brass-polishing instincts consume a lot of time. I would just tweak the if as mentioned above; comment the code and move on.

Comment: I think perfectionist, brass-polishing instincts save time in the long run.  Hopefully, with practice, you develop such habits so your code is perfect and its brass polished _without_ consuming a lot of time.  But unlike physical construction, software can last forever and be used in an infinite number of places.  The savings from code that's even 0.00000001% faster, more reliable, usable, and maintainable can be large.  (Of course, most of my much-polished code is in languages long obsolete or making money for someone else these days, but it _did_ help me develop good habits.)

Comment: Well I can't call you wrong :-) This *is* an opinion question and if good skills came out of the brass-polishing: great.

Comment: I think its a possibility to consider, anyway.  I certainly wouldn't want to offer any guarantees.  It does make me feel better to think that my brass-polishing improved my skills, so I may be prejudiced on this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with this:

```java
public void doSomething(int input)
{
   while(TransformInSomeWay(input), !ProcessingComplete(input))
   {
      DoSomethingElseTo(input);
   }
}
```

Or less confusingly:

```java
bool TransformAndCheckCompletion(int &input)
{
   TransformInSomeWay(input);
   return ProcessingComplete(input))
}

public void doSomething(int input)
{
   while(TransformAndCheckCompletion(input))
   {
      DoSomethingElseTo(input);
   }
}
```

Comment: While some people like it, I assert that the loop condition should generally be reserved for conditional tests, rather than statements that do stuff.

Comment: Comma expression in a loop condition... That's awful. You're too clever. And it only works in this trivial case where TransformInSomeWay can be expressed as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

If a particular flow of control is naturally expressed as a break statement, it is essentially never a better choice to use other flow control mechanisms to emulate a break statement.

(note that this includes partially unrolling the loop and sliding the loop body down so that the loop begin coincides with the conditional test)

If you can reorganize your loop so that the flow of control is naturally expressed by having a conditional check at the beginning of the loop, great. It might even be worth spending some time thinking about whether that is possible. But it not, don't try to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 0):

When the complexity of the logic becomes unwieldy then using an unbounded loop with mid-loop breaks for flow control does actually make some sense. I have a project with some code which looks like the following. (Notice the exception at the end of the loop.)

```java
L: for (;;) {
    if (someBool) {
        someOtherBool = doSomeWork();
        if (someOtherBool) {
            doFinalWork();
            break L;
        }
        someOtherBool2 = doSomeWork2();
        if (someOtherBool2) {
            doFinalWork2();
            break L;
        }
        someOtherBool3 = doSomeWork3();
        if (someOtherBool3) {
            doFinalWork3();
            break L;
        }
    }
    bitOfData = getTheData();
    throw new SomeException("Unable to do something for some reason.", bitOfData);
}
progressOntoOtherThings();
```

To do this logic without unbounded loop breaking, I would end up with something like the following:

```java
void method() {
    if (!someBool) {
        throwingMethod();
    }
    someOtherBool = doSomeWork();
    if (someOtherBool) {
        doFinalWork();
    } else {
        someOtherBool2 = doSomeWork2();
        if (someOtherBool2) {
            doFinalWork2();
        } else {
            someOtherBool3 = doSomeWork3();
            if (someOtherBool3) {
                doFinalWork3();
            } else {
                throwingMethod();
            }
        }
    }
    progressOntoOtherThings();
}
void throwingMethod() throws SomeException {
        bitOfData = getTheData();
        throw new SomeException("Unable to do something for some reason.", bitOfData);
}
```

So the exception is now thrown in a helper method. Also it has quite a lot of `if ... else` nesting. I'm not satisfied with this approach.

However, there is a third approach, which is probably most acceptable. Put the logic into a method, and just return when done. So if we take the first approach above and slightly refactor it, we get this:

```java
void method()
{
    myMethod(someBool);
    progressOntoOtherThings();
}

void myMethod()
{
    if (someBool) {
        someOtherBool = doSomeWork();
        if (someOtherBool) {
            doFinalWork();
            return;
        }
        someOtherBool2 = doSomeWork2();
        if (someOtherBool2) {
            doFinalWork2();
            return;
        }
        someOtherBool3 = doSomeWork3();
        if (someOtherBool3) {
            doFinalWork3();
            return;
        }
    }
    bitOfData = getTheData();
    throw new SomeException("Unable to do something for some reason.", bitOfData);
}
```